# Virtual Directory in Precompiled site not able to host html files

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms-authentication, pre-compilation

I have a msdeployed site, which will contain a virtual directory to a separate folder of content. when I host non pre-compiled (I.E. my IIS hosting website points to my project directory in Visual Studio).

On my local machine, I can redirect to a html page within the virtual directory, and the html page is displayed correctly. BUT, when I deploy the project to our staging server, I get the following error:

```
The file '/MedrioWeb/help/info/default.html' has not been pre-compiled, and cannot be requested. 
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean throwIfNotFound)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CreateInstanceFromVirtualPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, Type requiredBaseType, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandlerHelper(HttpContext context, String requestType, VirtualPath virtualPath, String physicalPath)
   at System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory.GetHandler(HttpContext context, String requestType, String virtualPath, String path)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

In the main, precompiled web application in IIS, I added the following extensions to the compilation\buildProviders:

```
<!-- forcing authentication for html pages -->
<add extension=".html" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
<add extension=".htm" type="System.Web.Compilation.PageBuildProvider" />
```

Next, I have a web.config in the virtual directory under the web application:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>

    </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
         <add name="HTML" path="*.html" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG"   type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
         <add name="HTM" path="*.htm" verb="GET, HEAD, POST, DEBUG" type="System.Web.UI.PageHandlerFactory" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
     </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**TL;DR:** I am getting and pre-compiled error for a non asp.net file type. I am only including the extension so that my custom form authentication module is used to verify the user is logged into see the html page. **Why is this not working with the precompiled code, vs my non pre-compiled version on my local machine?**

Comment: This is now low priority, I just removed the task in the msbuild to precompile the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, No biters?

I ended up removing our builds pre-compile task.